# Modificar parrafo sin afectar la tipografia

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

al pasar el mouse en la option menu attack se le agregar los arrows correspondiente pero lo que no me gusta es que me modifica la tipografia y no quiero eso ¿como puedo resolver este problema sin que este mismo se modifique?

Codigo del problema:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
     const music = new Audio('#');
     //music.play();
     //music.loop = true;
     //music.playbackRate = 2;
     //music.pause();
     //CARACTER
     const abomasnow = $('#abomasnow');
     const pikachu = $('#pikachu');
     $('.table_comments').html(`<p>PIKACHU:Hm.<br>
                What move?</p>`);
     const select = $('.table_option p');
     for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
         $(select[i]).mouseenter(() => {
             $(select[i]).addClass('fas fa-caret-right');
         });
         $(select[i]).mouseleave(() => {
             $(select[i]).removeClass('fas fa-caret-right');
         });
         $(select[i]).click(() => {
             if (select[i] == select[0]) {
                 alert('opcion 1');
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

```css
@import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/pokemon-fire-red');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.stadium div.enemy div.power_abomasnow,
.stadium div.user div.power_pikachu {
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #4f5d46;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 180px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.stadium div.enemy div.power_abomasnow .name,
.stadium div.user div.power_pikachu .name {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.stadium div.enemy div.power_abomasnow .name p,
.stadium div.user div.power_pikachu .name p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.stadium {
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/mvvkjMf/grass.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Pokemon Fire Red', sans-serif;
}

.stadium div.enemy img#abomasnow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 80px;
}

.stadium div.enemy div.power_abomasnow {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

.stadium div.enemy div.power_abomasnow .hp {
    width: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #4f5d46;
}

.stadium div.enemy div.power_abomasnow .hp .point {
    width: 55%;
    height: 8px;
    background: #70e6aa;
}

.stadium div.user img#pikachu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 60px;
}

.stadium div.user div.power_pikachu {
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

.stadium div.user div.power_pikachu .hp {
    width: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #4f5d46;
}

.stadium div.user div.power_pikachu .hp .point {
    width: 75%;
    height: 8px;
    background: #70e6aa;
}

.stadium .table_window {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #4f5d46;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
}

.stadium .table_window .table_comments {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #c8aa4a;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #245064;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

.stadium .table_window .table_option {
    width: inherit;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: inherit;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #706880;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Battle</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="stadium">
            <div class="enemy">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/MSdnshz/abomasnow.gif" id="abomasnow">
                <div class="power_abomasnow">
                    <div class="name">
                        <p>ABOMASNOW</p><p>Lv15</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hp">
                        <div class="point"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="user">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3NvdgK0/pikachu.gif" id="pikachu">
                <div class="power_pikachu">
                    <div class="name">
                        <p>PIKACHU</p><p>Lv13</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hp">
                        <div class="point"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table_window">
                <div class="table_comments"></div>
                <div class="table_option">
                    <p> FIGHT</p>
                    <p> BAG</p>
                    <p> POKéMON</p>
                    <p> RUN</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya que usas Fontawesome, por qué mejor no añades los iconos como dicha página te lo sugiere? Con elementos i, por ejemplo:`<i class="fab fa-500px"></i>`. Y así los puedes diferenciar fácilmente de los p

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de .table-option podés colocar elementos i

```
<div class="table_option">
    <p><i></i> FIGHT</p>
    <p><i></i> BAG</p>
    <p><i></i> POKéMON</p>
    <p><i></i> RUN</p>
</div>
```

Luego cambias la clase de éstos modificando los selectores de las líneas 15 y 18 a:

```
$(select[i]).children("i").addClass('fas fa-caret-right');
$(select[i]).children("i").removeClass('fas fa-caret-right');
```